# Extension of lte connectivity, usrp

Tags: lte

I would like to extend lte connectivity using usrp b2000 mini with GNURadioCompanion. I don't know what blocks to insert

I included blocks such as:
options
QT GUI Range
QT GUI Range
QT GUI Range
UHD:USRP Source
QT GUI Waterfall Sink
QT GUI Time Sink
QT GUI Frequency Sink
The frequencies of FM radio stations were visible.
I need to design a signal processing system that will meet the requirements of LTE. This includes creating blocks for modulation/demodulation, encoding/decoding, filtering, and other necessary signal processing functions.